# Expectation of max absolute value of a Gaussian vector

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a joint Gaussian vector of dimension $k$ with zero mean and covariance matrix $K$ (where $K$ may not be diagonal). I am interested in sharp estimates on

$$\mathbb{E}\max_{i=1,2,\ldots,k} |X_i|~.$$

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to go :

We know that the distribution is a gaussian vector and since we know the covariance matrix, we can compute the density function $f(x_1,x_2,..,x_k)$.

Using this we can compute the cumulative distribution function for $ \max_{i=1,2,..,k} |X_i|$. 
$$ P(\max_{i=1,2,..,k} |X_i| < x )= \int_{]-x,x[^{k}} f(x_1,x_2,..,x_k)dx_1dx_2...dx_k $$

Once we know that we can compute the expected value either by using the cumulative distribution function directly or by computing the density associated with it and do the usual calculation.

Comment: Thanks. Any possibility, this may have a closed-form expression?